# Bullets will only fire to the right?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a flash game for my course at college, I have been following a tutorial but been spinning it off for my own sake. One wall I hit is that when I fire a bullet, it will only fire to the right, with a little movement up or down, I have been trying to fix it for a while but nothing is happening and nothing works.

package {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Wizard extends MovieClip {

    private var dx:Number;
    private var dy:Number;
    private var Bulletspeed:int;
    public var Angle:Number;
    public var newAngle:Number;
    var shotCoolDown:int;
    const MAX_COOLDOWN=20;
    public function Wizard() {
        //constructor
        //Shot cool down
        shotCoolDown=MAX_COOLDOWN;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        //set up an event listener for when the turret is added to stage
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialise);




    }
    function initialise(e:Event) {
        //reduce shot cool down by one
        shotCoolDown=shotCoolDown-1;

        //add a click listener to the stage
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fire);
    }
    function fire(m:MouseEvent) {
        //Able to shoot
        if (shotCoolDown<=0) {
            //resets cool down
            shotCoolDown=MAX_COOLDOWN;
            //spawn bullet
            var B = new Bullet();
            //set position and rotation of the bullet
            B.rotation=rotation;
            B.x=x;
            B.y=y;
            //add the bullet the the wizard
            parent.addChild(B);
        }
    }

    function update():void {
        //Shot cool down
        shotCoolDown--;
        //Make the Wizard face the mouse
        if (parent!=null) {
            dx=stage.mouseX-this.x;
            dy=stage.mouseY-this.y;
            Math.abs(dx);
            Math.abs(dy);
            var Angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
            var newAngle = Angle * (180 / Math.PI);

            if ((0 < newAngle) && (newAngle <= 90)) {
                gotoAndPlay("Right");
            } else if ((90 < newAngle) && (newAngle <= 180)) {
                gotoAndPlay("Down");
            } else if ((-180 < newAngle) && (newAngle <= -90)) {
                gotoAndPlay("Left");
            } else if ((-90 < newAngle) && (newAngle <= 0)) {
                gotoAndPlay("Up");
            }

            this.rotation=Angle;

        }
    }
}
```

}

That's the code for my player class, with things such as bullets firing and what not. I think I know the problem, I need to link it to the rest of the Wizard update. But I don't know how, here is my bullet class if needed.

package {

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Bullet extends Sprite {

    private var speed:int;
    private var myCharacter:Wizard;



    public function Bullet() {
        //constructor
        speed = 10;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);


    }



    function update (e:Event) {
            //Move in the direction the bullet is facing
        x=x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*speed;
        y=y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*speed;
        //Clears bullet once it leaves the stage
        if (x<0 || x>500 || y<0 || y>500) {
            //removes the update listner
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

            parent.removeChild(this);




        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try replacing `B.rotation=rotation;` with `B.rotation=this.rotation;`

I'm pretty sure that `rotation` is undefined and that's why it's only going right (always set to 0)

try using `trace(rotation)` to see what the variable is at runtime.

Comment: I did that, but nothing, the angle stays between 1 and -1 every shot where ever i move it

Comment: rotation is a degree not a radian. try thisx=x+Math.cos(rotation)*speed;
and this y=y+Math.sin(rotation)*speed;

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `Wizard`'s `rotation` to `Angle`, which is in radians; the rotation is then passed on to the `Bullet`, which expects its rotation to be in degrees. It's probably better to set `this.rotation=newAngle;` at the end of `update()`, as the `UIComponent` class expects that value in degrees and uses it for rotating its drawing.